# Disable image preview in dialog box

Tags: image, electron, ubuntu-18.04

In my Electron app, I am trying to use `dialog.showOpenDialog()` to allow  users to choose the image file that they want to open. On Ubuntu 18.04, when they choose an image file, a preview of the image would appear on the right side like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6Po.png

However, if the user chooses a file that is too large (typically 1GB+), my app would crashes, with the following being printed on the command line:

```
tcmalloc: large alloc 1073741824 bytes == 0x32f584ab4000 @  0x7fb5985b16cf
```

I tried disable thumbnail generation in the Search & Preview tab of the file manager but it didn't disable this right-hand-side preview in the dialog box.

My app works with very large raster files so being able to choose these image files is crucial. I have considered either installing a new file manager or moving my code to another OS, but I want to ask beforehand if there is any less drastic solution that I can take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previews are being added to the [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) by [Electron itself](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/shell/browser/ui/file_dialog_gtk.cc#L370), so changing your file manager or its settings won't have an effect. Changing OS would work, of course, as drastic as it is.

It does seem like Electron should offer an option for turning off previews among the platform-specific ones in [`dialog.showOpenDialog`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options). At the minimum, it should enforce a reasonable cutoff on file sizes for previews.

To accomplish that, you'd have to patch Electron locally (and then ideally submit a PR). Whatever you decide to do, I don't see a bug reported about this in the Electron repo, so doing that could be helpful to anyone else who runs into the problem.